# How can a server handle HTTP requests in the order in which they were sent?

Tags: http, server, request, client

I'm building a simple CRUD application where there is a client, a server, and a database.

The client can send two types of requests to the server:

- POST requests that update a row in the database.
- GET requests that retrieve a row in the database.

One requirement of my application is that the requests have to be handled in the order in which they were sent from the client. For example, if the user makes a POST request to update row 1 in the database, then they make a GET request to retrieve row 1 in the database, the response to GET request must reflect the changes made by the previous POST request. One issue is that there is no guarantee that the server will receive the requests in the same order that the requests went sent. Therefore, in the example above, it is possible that the server might receive the GET request first, then the POST request later, which makes the response to the GET request not able to reflect the changes made by the previous POST request.

Another requirement of the application is that the client should not have to wait for the server's response before sending another request (this constraint is to allow for faster runtime). So in the example above, one possible solution is let the client wait for the server response to the POST request, and then it can send the GET request to retrieve the updated row. This solution is not desirable under this constraint.

My current solution is as follows:

1. Maintain a variable on the client that keeps track of the count of all the requests a user has sent so far. And then append this variable to the request body once the request is sent. So if the user makes a POST request first, the POST request's body will contain `count=1`, e.g. And then if they make a GET request, the GET request's body will contain `count=2`. This variable can be maintained using localStorage on the client, so it guarantees that the count variable accurately reflects the order in which the request was made.
2. On the server side, I create a new thread every time a new request is received. Let's say that this request has `count=n`. This thread is locked until the request that contains `count=n-1` has been completed (by another thread). This ensures that the server also completes the requests in the order maintained by the `count` variable, which was the order in which the request was made in the client.

However, the problem with my current  solution is that once the user clears their browsing data, localStorage will also be cleared. This results in the `count` getting reset to 0, which makes subsequent requests be placed in a weird order.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution in your case is probably to use a websocket protocol to handle the communication between the client and the server. You can read more on websocket from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).